# Angular - Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I have set up an angular and express app with `angular-cli` and `express` command lines respectively. I've already build angular app with `ng build` and when I want to serve it with express server I get following error in google chrome console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    runtime.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    polyfills.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    styles.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    vendor.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    main.js:1
```

here is my server.js file:

```
.
.
.
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/auth', authRouter);

// Catch all other routes and return the angular index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/dist/client/index.html'));
});
```

index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Client</title>
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

There is no problem with `ng serve` and app will run smoothly and also when I just open index.html with browser it also works, I think it somehow relates to express server.

Comment: What directory are the five JS files stored in (runtime, polyfills, styles, vendor, and main) that you include in index.html?

Comment: @thmsdnnr same as "index.html". They are all in "client/dist/client/" directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that your script files are loaded from the root level making your browser request `http://example.com/XXX.js`. That's why they fall in the Express' `*` route. This means every request for XXX.js gets the same `index.html` file which can't be properly parsed by JS engine.

Comment: This mostly depend on your application's setup. You could change where Angular builds the files by using `ng build -o ./public`  or modyfing the Angular CLI configuration's `outDir` value.

Comment: I don't know much about serverjs, but I supouse you can, in your get(*) get the req and if the req.url ends in .js server the file.js not the index.html

Answer (score 5):

Like Mateusz said - all of your requests are returning the index.html file.  If you open up the developer tools in Chrome and look under the "Network" tab and view the responses for each of those files you'll see the contents of each of those files is actually the index.html file.  What you need to do is make an list of exceptions to allow the server to return those js files and other file types like images.

```
const allowed = [
  '.js',
  '.css',
  '.png',
  '.jpg'
];

// Catch all other routes and return the angular index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   if (allowed.filter(ext => req.url.indexOf(ext) > 0).length > 0) {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(`client/dist/cient/${req.url}`));
   } else {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/dist/client/index.html'));
   }
});
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for hours. Thank you for explaining this so clearly!!

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed a similar problem myself, by moving my server.js file from the DIST folder into the directory above.

So my folder/file structure looks like this:

- webroot - root folder

  - server.js
  - dist (folder)

    - browser (subfolder)
    - server (subfolder)

Answer (score -1):

in your `index.ts` change

```
<!--doctype html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

because **The <!DOCTYPE> declaration is NOT case sensitive.**
check the following [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)