# webpack-hot-middleware not serving any file

Tags: javascript, express, webpack, hot-reload

I followed the tutorial from the GitHub page of `webpack-hot-middleware` and I just can't make it work. I receive in the browser the next: `index.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` because can't find the file. I know that `webpack-dev-middleware` serve the file in memory, but I don't know how to make it work.

Here is the server.js:

```
//...

var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackConfig = require('./../webpack.config');
var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

console.log("QQQ", webpackConfig.output.publicPath);

app.use(require("webpack-dev-middleware")(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath
}));
app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler, {
    log: console.log,
    path: '/__webpack_hmr',
    heartbeat: 10 * 1000
}));

//...

app.get('*', async (req, res) => {
    //...

    res.render('index', {
        //...
    });
});

const server = new http.Server(app); // Create a server through Express
server.listen(process.env.NODE_PORT, err => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.info(`Server running on http://localhost:${process.env.NODE_PORT}`);
});
```

And here it the `index.ejs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui" />

        <base href="/">

        <meta name="keywords" content="<%- keywords %>" />
        <meta name="description" content="<%- description %>" />
        <title><%- title %></title>

        <!-- ... -->

        <!-- PRERENDER:DELETE -->
        <script defer src="/js/index.bundle.js"></script>
        <script defer src="/js/vendor.chunk.js"></script>
        <!-- PRERENDER:END -->

        <%- headOther.toString() %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in final here it is the `webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

module.exports = {
    mode: isProduction ? "production" : "development",
    entry: {
        index: [
            "webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000",
            path.join(__dirname, "src", "client.js")
        ]
    },
    context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    output: {
        path: path.join(process.env.IMOCENTRAL_SITE_DATA, "static"),
        publicPath: "/js/",
        chunkFilename: "js/[name].chunk.js",
        filename: "js/[name].bundle.js"
    },
    devtool: isProduction ? undefined : "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.tem\.js$/],
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    cacheDirectory: "babel_cache",
                    presets: ["@babel/react", ["@babel/env", { modules: false, useBuiltIns: "usage", corejs: 2 }]],
                    plugins: [
                        ["@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread"],
                        ["@babel/plugin-syntax-async-generators"],
                        ["@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator"],
                        ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"],
                        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
                        ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
                    ]
                }
            },
            //...
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __production: isProduction ? "true" : "false",
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(isProduction ? "production" : "development"),
            AppConfig: JSON.stringify(require("./src/data/MainData").default)
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all",
            maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
            minSize: 0,
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /node_modules/,
                    chunks: "initial",
                    name: "vendor",
                    enforce: true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")],
        alias: {
            ExternalStyles: path.join(process.env.IMOCENTRAL_SITE_DATA, "styles")
        },
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    externals: {
        fs: "{}",
        tls: "{}",
        net: "{}",
        console: "{}",
        v8: "{}"
    }
}
```

`IMOCENTRAL_SITE_DATA` is a location outside of project folder.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error in my MEAN stack project. The app.get method originally only had the path to the index.html file. When I clicked on the file names causing the error in Chrome developer tools Console tab, it showed that when it was looking for the js files, it only found the index.html file:

[Chrome dev tools Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsW23.png)
[Chrome dev tools Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13CRI.png)

I'm not sure if my solution will be the same as yours because I'm not using webpack, and I'm also new to MEAN/express :) but just in case it helps, the last answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028765/angular-unexpected-token) fixed it for me.

i.e. Adding to server.js:

```
    const allowed = [
  '.js',
  '.css',
  '.png',
  '.jpg'
];

app.get('*', function(req, res) {       
    if (allowed.filter(ext => req.url.indexOf(ext) > 0).length > 0) {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(`dist/meantodo/${req.url}`));
   } else {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/meantodo/index.html'));
   }
});
```